# While doing flip animation in Android Grid View

Tags: android, animation, gridview

Problem while doing flip animation in grideview.I want which ever item i click in grid view that should rotate, I followed this link  https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/source/browse/ and tried to implement in gridview by taking seperate view group like linear layout for each item in grid view but no sucess. The problem is when i am clicking any item in gridview only first and last items are flipping. Plz help me.

Answer (score 0):

This below code is for understand purpose, you can do animation with following code useage

```
if (position == 0) {
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.frame);
            mAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) v.getBackground();
            v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (mAnimation != null)
                        mAnimation .start();
                }
            }, 100);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , I tried but raising same problem this is my code FlipAnimator animator = new FlipAnimator(holder.back, holder.front,
       holder.front.getWidth() / 2, holder.front.getHeight() / 2);
             if (holder.back.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
         animator.reverse();
                  
            }
            T
      holder.layout.startAnimation(animator);
            notifyDataSetChanged();